# How to use a hook from a different component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm calling a component `<B setHasChecked={()=>{setCheckedClientId(true)}}/>` from within component "A", inside component "A" I declare the hook `const [checkedClientId, setCheckedClientId] = useState(false);`, and inside component "B" I execute `props.setHasChecked();`.
Even though this is working fine, i still get an error on the console:
React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by "A"

```
Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useState                   useState
2. undefined                  useRef`
```

Comment: Can you provide a code block with issues? Like Component A. With just above a few words, we can't solve your problem. Please.

Comment: that seems not the error related `setHasChecked` - I guess you do something like show/hide element as per `checkedClientId` changed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

that's because you are not passing any parameter to props.setHasChecked();

Comment: i don't need to pass any params, because the function "setHasChecked", already changes the value of the hook to true, ```setHasChecked={()=>{setCheckedClientId(true)}}```

Comment: hooks don´t work like that, if you don´t want to use parameters, create a function and call it instead your hook, later inside your function use your hook setCheckedClientId(true)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest better pass a callback function from `A` to `B`. And in the callback function which resides in `A` you can call the `setChecked` function.